# How did Trish find Jessica?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones-2015

So at the end (the last episode) of season 2 of Jessica Jones...

> Jessica and her mom are hiding out in a carnival, and then out of nowhere Trish shows up with a gun and kills the mom. How did Trish figure out they were hiding at the carnival?!

How did Trish know to go to that place? I don't remember a scene explaining how she figured out where to track Jessica down in all of NYC.

Comment: It's unclear, the only suggestion is that Alisa used to take Jessica when she was a kid and Jessica may have told Trish about it.

Comment: @Edlothiad It's the same place they disposed of the body earlier in the season, and Jessica tells Trish all about how they went there all the time when she was a kid.

Comment: There you go, seems like an obvious place to check then!